# How to detect objects in addition to coco dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I'm using tensorflow objection detection API with the coco dataset provided in the tutorial.

If I use the api to detect custom objects, how do I "add" to the list of objects being detected from the coco dataset? Is there a way to merge?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean using a model which is trained on the COCO dataset to detect objects that are not in the COCO dataset, you cannot do that. I think you will need to train a model, in this case one already trained on COCO, on your new objects that you want to detect. There is a tutorial [here](https://medium.com/towards-data-science/how-to-train-your-own-object-detector-with-tensorflows-object-detector-api-bec72ecfe1d9) that shows how to train a model on a custom dataset.

If you do not want to train a model you need to find one that is already trained for the objects that you want to detect.

Have I understood correctly?

Comment: No. For example, I want to detect all the objects in coco dataset plus a custom object that I want to detect. So everything in coco plus additional. Not just one or other but combined

Comment: But if this custom object is not contained into the COCO dataset the detector does not have a clue about it So I think you will need to find a model that already contains all the objects ( COCO + custom ) or train one which is specialized on COCO to add the custom one. You cannot ''add" objects like this to a detector which is working with Neural Nets if the Neural Net is not trained on those particular objects.

Comment: yeah, that's what i was afraid of... trying to avoid having to re-train on entire coco dataset + my own custom.. ugh..

Comment: Btw what is this custom object? Maybe someone has already done it and a model with all the objects has already been trained...

Comment: No. I've never heard of one, sorry.